# How to auto update sub elements datum binding in D3

Tags: d3.js

All:

I am pretty new to D3 data binding, what I am trying to understand is how D3 controls the datum update, for example, I want to build a row of buttons, the structure is span wrap a button:

```
<span><button>1</button></span>
<span><button>2</button></span>
<span><button>3</button></span>
```

And code is like:

```
var ds1 = [1,2,3,4]
var ds2 = [11,22,33,44]

var cells = d3.select("#content")
    .selectAll("span button.cell")
    .data(ds1)
cells.enter()
    .append("span")
    .append("button")
    .classed("cell", true)
    .text(function(d, i){
        return d;
    })
```

But when I try to update ds2, with update function below, each d is previous datum, like 1,2,3,4.

```
function update(data){
    cells.data(data)
        .selectAll("button.cell")
        .text(function(d, i){
            return d;
        })
}
```

**I wonder how can I make the new data bind to those buttons?**

Comment: you need to use update() exit() etc look at this link : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

Comment: @thisOneGuy Thanks, but the problem I try to solve is more like how to rebind data rather than remove unused elements. Could u who me some code about how to do this?

Comment: Thisoneguy, you mean an "update selection". There is no `update()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to rebind the data without creating an enter, update and exit selection is just setting the data to a selection containing the buttons:

```
function update(data) {
    var update = d3.selectAll(".cell")
        .data(data)
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var ds1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var ds2 = [11, 22, 33, 44]

var cells = d3.select("#content")
    .selectAll("span button.cell")
    .data(ds1, function(d, i) {
        return i
    });

cells.enter()
    .append("span")
    .append("button")
    .classed("cell", true)
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;
    });

function update(data) {

    var update = d3.selectAll(".cell")
        .data(data)
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
}

d3.select("#btn").on("click", function() {
    update(ds2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<br>
<button id="btn">Update</button>
```

Alternatively, to update the data using `cells` as you did in your question, just select the buttons inside your update selection:

```
function update(data) {
    cells.data(data)
    var update = cells.select(".cell")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
}
```

Here is the respective demo:

```js
var ds1 = [1,2,3,4]
var ds2 = [11,22,33,44]

var cells = d3.select("#content")
    .selectAll("span button.cell")
    .data(ds1, function(d,i){ return i});
  
cells.enter()
    .append("span")
    .append("button")
    .classed("cell", true)
    .text(function(d){
        return d;
    });
 
function update(data){

cells.data(data)

    var update = cells.select(".cell")
  .text(function(d){
            return d;
        })
}

d3.select("#btn").on("click", function(){
    update(ds2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<br>
<button id="btn">Update</button>
```